# Salesforce report sharing by roles

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I created one report and moved it to a folder and shared the folder only with the Role called "Role 1" and when I login as a user with a different role say "Role 2", I am still able to see and run the reports. I expect the folder will be only visible to the user with "Role 1" Or when I ran I thought I might get "Insufficient privileges'...." but it behaved differently. Is my understanding on the report sharing is correct ?

Comment: is Role2 above Role1 in the hierarchy? Or maybe that Role2 user you picked is special (sysadmin? normal user but with "Manage Reports in Public Folders", "View Reports in Public Folders" permissions granted via profile / permsets?

Comment: Role 2 is not special, just random user and not up in the hierarchy as well for sure, as you pointed out I need check permissions granted through Profiles.